# Confused on how to use the following data in a select tag (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following data in my controller:

```
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May",
              "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
var years = ["1999", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006",    
             "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010"]

$scope.selects = [
  { text: 'Month', values: months },
  { text: 'Year', values: years }
]
```

And the following `select` tag:

```
<select class="form-control col-3" ng-repeat="select in selects" ng-model="">
  <option value="" disabled selected>{{ select.text }}</option>
  <option value="{{ value }}" ng-repeat="value in select.values" >{{ value }}</option>
</select>
```

I'm not very sure what to put in `ng-model=""`. I want to the `options` to set each `select` with the values inside `months` and `years`.

How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add property `selected` to each select:

```
$scope.selects = [
  { text: 'Month', values: months, selected: '' },
  { text: 'Year', values: years, selected: '' }
]
```

And then use it as model:

```
<select class="form-control col-3" ng-repeat="select in selects" ng-model="select.selected">
```

Comment: Sponge Thanks!. How does it work? How does `selected` know which value to get (from each `option`)?

Comment: In `ng-model="select.selected"` you specify local variable `select` that have scope of specific select and its options.

Answer (score 2):

You can directly use your properties without adding extra properties to each elements:
There is an angular directive [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) you can use it like this.

```
$scope.selects = [
  { text: 'Month', values: months },
  { text: 'Year', values: years }
]
```

Use this object in your select as:

```
    <select class="form-control col-3" ng-options="select as select.text for select in selects" ng-model="select"></select>

<select class="form-control col-3" ng-options="select as select for select in select" ng-model="select"></select>
```

Here first dropdown is use to select either month or Year and second is use to values with respect to your first dropdown.

"HAPPY CODING"